# How to solve printing problems after upgrading chrome to version 108.0.5359.99?

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

Help everyone! **Chrome print preview** is a problem when the user's chrome was automatically upgraded to version **108**.

I configuring the **rowspan** attribute of the **td** element in the **table** element make **the merged row** to exceed one page, it will **break**. Like those pic.

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="16">5</td>
    <td rowspan="16">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="5">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

[html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nrTV.png)

[preview break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqZ8d.png)

But the same webpage is normal when it is **displayed**, and it is also normal in **107** and earlier versions. Like this pic.

[preview normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYyjA.png)

I found the log for chrome. [chrome-108](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-108-beta/)
Then added the style, but there are still some break.

```
tr {
    break-after: aviod;
    break-before: aviod;
    break-inside: aviod;
}
```

[There are still some break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZM51.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue on all browsers using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="print-container">
   <div id="page1" class="page"></div>
   <div id="page2" class="page"></div>
   <div id="page3" class="page"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.print-container {
    contain: strict;
    display: table
}
.page {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    page-break-before: unset !important;
}
.page:last-of-type {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```